# 'Main.this' cannot be referenced from a static context if outer class is generified

Tags: java, generics

Why is the following code ok, but as soon as T is added to Main as a generic, it throws the following error?

> 'Main.this' cannot be referenced from a static context

```
//public class Main<T> { - uncomment this for the error to appear

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    class TestNonStatic {}

    private static class TestStatic {
        public TestStatic(TestNonStatic nonStatic) { //this is the line that fails

        }
    }
}
```

I went through [generics restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html) but I don't get it why this results into an error.
I also went through a lot of similar questions but I don't understand why adding the generic would change the situation.

Comment: That's fine.  I admit I did take a glance at it and also agreed. Glad someone decided to overturn this before I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `TestNonStatic` has an implicit generic which you have to specify whether it is a raw type

```
    public TestStatic(Main.TestNonStatic nonStatic) {
```

or a generic type

```
    public TestStatic(Main<String>.TestNonStatic nonStatic) {
```

or using a non-static class

```
private class TestStatic {
    public TestStatic(/*Main<T>.*/TestNonStatic nonStatic) {
```

It won't implicitly assume the following, as the class is `static`

```
    public TestStatic(Main<T>.TestNonStatic nonStatic) {
```

Why doesn't have some default behaviour, possibly because this might lead to even more obscure error messages ;)